# borders in table not showing up in IE11 for tds with triangle at corner

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

```css
td {
    padding: 20px;
}
.note {
    position: relative;
}
.note:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
    display: block;
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
 
 border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="note">Triangle!</td>
        <td>No Triangle!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With angular and tooltip I am indicating triangle for hovering field -td but then borders for the respective td or tr are coming fine in chrome, mozilla but not in IE11.

Comment: I checked it out in IE11 and cannot see the problem. I can see the triangle and the border exactly as I see in Chrome

Comment: but for me not working in ie11. border-left and border-right not coming up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've given works just fine in IE11, but does not work in IE7.

The problem is that IE is falling into IE7 compatibility mode.

This generally happens when you run code locally while testing. There is an IE setting that tells IE to use compatibility mode for local intranet sites. This setting is designed for businesses who need to upgrade IE but don't want to update their systems that rely on older versions.

You can fix it by adding the `x-ua-compatible` meta tag to your HTML code, or by simply changing the relevant config setting in your browser.